# How to find the source code for a ROS 2 package, say, turtlesim?

Tags: ros2, turtlesim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see that ROS2 tutorials uses turtlesim, but where is the source code (on Github) for the ROS2 turtlesim package? The one on GitHub seems to target ROS1 or maybe I am wrong.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381559/how-to-find-the-source-code-for-a-ros-2-package,-say,-turtlesim?/) by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 186 on 2021-07-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-02**:
@Zhoulai Fu: would it perhaps be an idea to make your question (title) a little more generic? Something like "how to find the source code for ROS 2 packages?", and then use the turtlesim package as an example for which you'd like to find the source?

I feel that would help future users find the Q&A more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit: for future readers: please *always* prefer to install the binary version of ROS packages, if at all possible.

Building ROS packages from sources is **not** the recommended way to install them and should *not* be your default.

---

Easiest way to find source code for released (and indexed) packages would be [index.ros.org](https://index.ros.org).

For `turtlesim` specifically: [index.ros.org/p/turtlesim](https://index.ros.org/p/turtlesim/github-ros-ros_tutorials/):

[image: ros index]

In the screenshot:

1. the main link to the source repository. In this case: https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials.git
2. the name of the branch. In this case: `galactic-devel`
3. tabs which allow you to switch to a different ROS release. Note how *GALACTIC* is selected here. To switch to the Foxy version of the package/page, click the *FOXY* tab. The *VCS Version* field in the *Repository Summary* will automatically update to show the correct branch name (for Foxy it would switch to `foxy-devel`)
4. a convenience button which will take you to the source repository and open the correct branch for the package version selected using the tabs (3). In this case: https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials/tree/galactic-devel/turtlesim

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) on 2021-07-01**:
it's also good to point out that you should select the ROS distro you're using near the top of the page. Then if you want to clone the repo or just look at the code, you should use the branch that's next to "VCS Version" in the summary (in this case `galactic-devel`), otherwise you might not get the right code or version of the code. If you click "Browse Code" on the right panel, it should lead you to the directory corresponding to the package on the right branch in the repo.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-02**:
Good suggestion.

I've updated the screenshot and highlighted the various elements in the UI and their function.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe this is what you are looking for:
https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials/tree/foxy-devel/turtlesim

---

Originally posted by [vinny](https://answers.ros.org/users/52902/vinny/) with karma: 291 on 2021-07-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1